# How to import a .obj in electron-vue webpack project with vue-3d-model

Tags: vue.js, webpack, three.js, electron, objloader

Here is my first question to the community :)

My name is Victor, I'm learning programming by myself so I hope I'll be able to explain my problem correctly to you with enough informations.

I'm building an **electron + vuejs + vuetify app** in which I want to **display 3D models (.obj)**

I found a library named **vue-3d-model** which seems to be appropriate for that.

After installing the library and following the tutorial, I got this error when trying to execute my app:

*Failed to compile.
./src/assets/model1.obj 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders*

I looked for solutions on internet but I failed finding how to fix my issue.
I guess this is linked to **webpack**.

here is my **obj_loader.vue**:

```
<template>
  <model-obj :src="require('../assets/model1.obj')"></model-obj>
</template>

<script>
import { ModelObj } from 'vue-3d-model';
export default {
  components: { ModelObj }
}
</script>
```

And here are the **dependencies** of my project:

```
  *"dependencies": {
    "@amcharts/amcharts4": "^4.9.36",
    "animated-number-vue": "^1.0.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-3d-model": "^1.3.1",
    "vue-responsive-video-background-player": "^1.1.2",
    "vuetify": "^2.2.11",
    "vuex": "^3.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "^4.5.4",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "electron": "^9.0.0",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^3.1.0",
    "electron-icon-builder": "^1.0.2",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "sass": "^1.19.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder": "~2.0.0-rc.4",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.0.7",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.3.0"
  },*
```

finally, I guess I've to put something in **my index.js regarding webpack**:

```
*/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId]) {
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
/******/        }
/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            i: moduleId,
/******/            l: false,
/******/            exports: {}
/******/        };
/******/
/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
/******/
/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.l = true;
/******/
/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }
/******/
/******/
/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;
/******/
/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;
/******/
/******/    // define getter function for harmony exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
/******/        if(!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, name, { enumerable: true, get: getter });
/******/        }
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // define __esModule on exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.r = function(exports) {
/******/        if(typeof Symbol !== 'undefined' && Symbol.toStringTag) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: 'Module' });
/******/        }
/******/        Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // create a fake namespace object
/******/    // mode & 1: value is a module id, require it
/******/    // mode & 2: merge all properties of value into the ns
/******/    // mode & 4: return value when already ns object
/******/    // mode & 8|1: behave like require
/******/    __webpack_require__.t = function(value, mode) {
/******/        if(mode & 1) value = __webpack_require__(value);
/******/        if(mode & 8) return value;
/******/        if((mode & 4) && typeof value === 'object' && value && value.__esModule) return value;
/******/        var ns = Object.create(null);
/******/        __webpack_require__.r(ns);
/******/        Object.defineProperty(ns, 'default', { enumerable: true, value: value });
/******/        if(mode & 2 && typeof value != 'string') for(var key in value) __webpack_require__.d(ns, key, function(key) { return value[key]; }.bind(null, key));
/******/        return ns;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // getDefaultExport function for compatibility with non-harmony modules
/******/    __webpack_require__.n = function(module) {
/******/        var getter = module && module.__esModule ?
/******/            function getDefault() { return module['default']; } :
/******/            function getModuleExports() { return module; };
/******/        __webpack_require__.d(getter, 'a', getter);
/******/        return getter;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call
/******/    __webpack_require__.o = function(object, property) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property); };
/******/
/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";
/******/
/******/
/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = 0);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/*
```

If you can help me with this issue, it would be amazing! :)
Thank you for having taking the time to read my problem.

Comment: Could you provide your webpack config too?

Comment: Hello kmgt. Do you mean all my index.js ?

Comment: I see. You dont have specified a config file (webpack.config.js), the app using the default config. I think you have to get a config file to append a loader for obj files.

Comment: Ok kmgt. Again thank you for your help. I'm not really used to programming :( Maybe you know a tutorial to create this config file ?

Comment: Hope the answer will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time kmgt. I will check this out.

Comment: You have to define the webpack-obj-loader. Therefore you have to create a working config file. Anyway it is recommended to have controll over webpack.

Comment: I finally found how to add obj loader to Webpack using this:                 module.exports = {
  "transpileDependencies": [
    "vuetify"
  ],

  chainWebpack: config => {

    config.module
      .rule()
      .test(/\.obj$/)
      .use()
        .loader('webpack-obj-loader')
        .end()
  }

} but now I get a new error:                                                                                     [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "src". Expected String with value "[object Module]", got Module

Answer (score 0):

Follow this guide to create a config file [webpack.js.org/configuration/](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/) (at the bottom of the page)

```
npx webpack-cli init
```

You will get a config file with a rules section. Install this loader [webpack-obj-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-obj-loader)

```
npm i webpack-obj-loader
```

and append a new rule to your webpack config:

```
...
loaders: [
    ...
    {
        test: /\.obj$/,
        loader: 'webpack-obj-loader'
    }
    ...
]
...
```